# listbox xml datasource correct headers and output

Tags: c#, xml, linq, listbox

I am using windows forms and I cant seem to get the listbox to display the below xml data with the correct column headers, this is all I have so far on button click:

```
var moreHorays = xDoc.Descendants("Horay")
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    ISBN = n.Element("ID").Value,
                    Title = n.Element("blabla").Value,
                    SubTitle = n.Element("horay").Value
                })
                .ToList();
```

The output in the list box is `{ ID = 0000, blabla = blabla }` etc, it doesnt show the correct headers or it all neatly packaged.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a DataGridView instead of ListBox?

Comment: I have been looking into using a datagrid just dont know how yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DisplayMember that you are setting is not valid and is being ignored. If you want to set the DisplayMember to "ISBN", "Title", or "SubTitle" you would see the corresponding values in the ListBox.

If you want some different formatting for the display that combines more than one or all the values I would suggest creating a helper class to store the values and overriding ToString() to format your display as you desire.